# Haskell custom style instance show for Data type with list

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create a instance Show for my data type Family with the following structure:

```
x
  y1
  y2
  y3
```

I've come up with this:

```
import Data.List

data Family = Family {x :: String, y :: [[Char]]} deriving (Eq,Read)

-- this function prints the y in a new line with two spaces before
printY ys = putStrLn(foldr (++) "" (map (\str -> "  " ++ str ++ "\n") ys))

instance Show Family where
    show x = show x ++ "\n"
    show y = show printY y
```

But I get this error:

```
* Couldn't match expected type `Family -> String'
                  with actual type `[Char]'
    * The function `show' is applied to two arguments,
      but its type `([[Char]] -> IO ()) -> [Char]' has only one
      In the expression: show printme descendentes
      In an equation for `show':
          show descendentes = show printme descendentes
   |
22 |         show y = show printY y
```

How could I fix this and get the show style I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` and `y` aren't `Family` constructors. It looks like you're trying to pattern match on the fields of `Family`, but you can't do that with how you have things set up.

I think what you were going for was something like:

```
instance Show Family where
    show (Family x y) = (show x) ++ "\n" ++ (printY y)
```

Note though, your `printY` function is "broken". Try writing a type signature for it. The problem is, you're printing in the function, which goes against the goal of turning the object into a String, which is what `show` is supposed to do. Change `printY` to `showY`, and remove the call to `putStrLn`.

Answer (score 0):

The type of show as defined by the Show typeclass is:

```
forall a. Show a => a -> String
```

For your Family type it would specialize to:

```
Show Family => Family -> String
```

You need to define the instance to match the above type:

```
instance Show Family where
  show (Family x ys) = ...
```

And be sure to return a String.